# Android - Unable to start receiver com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, push-notification, parse-platform

I am trying to test a very basic push notification program using Parse, but my app crashes when I broadcast a notification. This is my error log.

```
    10-02 23:21:45.625: E/AndroidRuntime(6133): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    10-02 23:21:45.625: E/AndroidRuntime(6133): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver: java.lang.NullPointerException
    10-02 23:21:45.625: E/AndroidRuntime(6133):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2372)
    10-02 23:21:45.625: E/AndroidRuntime(6133):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:149)
    10-02 23:21:45.625: E/AndroidRuntime(6133):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1376)
    10-02 23:21:45.625: E/AndroidRuntime(6133):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    10-02 23:21:45.625: E/AndroidRuntime(6133):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
    10-02 23:21:45.625: E/AndroidRuntime(6133):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4987)
    10-02 23:21:45.625: E/AndroidRuntime(6133):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    10-02 23:21:45.625: E/AndroidRuntime(6133):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    10-02 23:21:45.625: E/AndroidRuntime(6133):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:821)
    10-02 23:21:45.625: E/AndroidRuntime(6133):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
    10-02 23:21:45.625: E/AndroidRuntime(6133):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    10-02 23:21:45.625: E/AndroidRuntime(6133): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    10-02 23:21:45.625: E/AndroidRuntime(6133):     at com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver.getSmallIconId(ParsePushBroadcastReceiver.java:253)
    10-02 23:21:45.625: E/AndroidRuntime(6133):     at com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver.getNotification(ParsePushBroadcastReceiver.java:335)
    10-02 23:21:45.625: E/AndroidRuntime(6133):     at com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver.onPushReceive(ParsePushBroadcastReceiver.java:143)
    10-02 23:21:45.625: E/AndroidRuntime(6133):     at com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver.onReceive(ParsePushBroadcastReceiver.java:104)
    10-02 23:21:45.625: E/AndroidRuntime(6133):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2365)
    10-02 23:21:45.625: E/AndroidRuntime(6133):     ... 10 more
```

Could somebody please tell me why the ParsePushBroadcaseReceiver does not start ?  It may also help to know that my application "failed to subscribe for push" when I call:

```
ParsePush.subscribeInBackground("channel_name", new SaveCallback() {
      @Override
      public void done(ParseException e) {
        if (e != null) {
          Log.v("com.parse.push", "successfully subscribed to the broadcast channel.");
        } else {
          Log.v("com.parse.push", "failed to subscribe for push", e);
        }
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add this line in project's manifest.

```
 <meta-data
            android:name="com.parse.push.notification_icon"
            android:resource="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
```

Comment: This works, thanks! If anyone still get the error even after adding this meta tag, make sure you put the correct icon name because that was what happen in my case.

Comment: [Edit] Also worked for me :-) thanks! Has to go in the manifest inside the Application tag.

Comment: I useded this line in this way. <meta-data
            android:name="com.parse.push.notification_icon"
            android:resource="@drawable/icon" />

Comment: Why does this work? What does adding this meta-data tag have to do with starting the receiver?