# Parse Unity Push Sample not working

Tags: parse-platform

I am struggling of using Parse on my Unity android application. Have been working on several days but no success yet. No matter how hard I try, I couldn't get my device token registered for Android which is needed for sending push notifications to android. Below is my sample code and manifest snippet..

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
  <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
  <permission android:protectionLevel="signature"      android:name="com.JoyDash.Movies.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="com.JoyDash.Movies.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />


 <!--Parse Push notification receiver-->
    <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />
    <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <receiver android:name="com.JoyDash.Movies.Receiver" android:exported="false">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
        <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <receiver android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
        <category android:name="com.JoyDash.Movies" />
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <!--<receiver android:name="com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
        <category android:name="com.JoyDash.Movies" />
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service android:name="com.parse.ParsePushService" />-->


#if UNITY_IOS
        NotificationServices.RegisterForRemoteNotificationTypes (RemoteNotificationType.Alert |
                                                                 RemoteNotificationType.Badge |
                                                                 RemoteNotificationType.Sound);
#endif

            //ParsePush.SubscribeAsync
            Debug.Log("Registration with Parse Push. : " + Application.platform);
            ParsePush.ParsePushNotificationReceived += (sender, args) =>
            {
                if (Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.Android)
                {
                    AndroidJavaClass parseUnityHelper = new AndroidJavaClass("com.parse.ParseUnityHelper");
                    AndroidJavaClass unityPlayer = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
                    AndroidJavaObject currentActivity = unityPlayer.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");

                    // Call default behavior.
                    Debug.Log("Calling Parse from Unity and Payload is : " + args.Payload);
                    parseUnityHelper.CallStatic("handleParsePushNotificationReceived", currentActivity, args.Payload.ToString());
                    //parseUnityHelper.CallStatic("handleParsePushNotificationReceived", currentActivity, args.Payload.StringPayload);
                }
                else if (Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.IPhonePlayer)
                {
                    //IDictionary<string, object> payload = args.Payload;

                    //foreach (string key in payload) 
                    //{
                    //    Debug.Log("Payload: " + key + ": " + payload[key].ToString());
                    //}
                }

            };

            //Parse Installation
            Debug.Log("Device Token : " + ParseInstallation.CurrentInstallation.DeviceToken);
            if (ParseInstallation.CurrentInstallation != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(ParseInstallation.CurrentInstallation.DeviceToken))
            {
                Debug.Log("Device Token : " + ParseInstallation.CurrentInstallation.DeviceToken);
            }
            else
            {
                //Create a new parse installation
                //ParseInstallation.CurrentInstallation.SaveAsync().ContinueWith(t =>
                //    {
                //        if (t.IsFaulted || t.IsCanceled)
                //        {
                //            Debug.Log("Parse installation failed to save.");
                //        }
                //        else
                //        {
                //            Debug.Log("Parse installation saved successfully.");
                //        }
                //    });

                //ParseInstallation.cre
                Debug.Log("There is no installation data received for this device.. Now subscribing to a channel");
                ParsePush.SubscribeAsync("Channel01").ContinueWith(t =>
                {
                    if (t.IsFaulted || t.IsCanceled)
                    {
                        Debug.Log("Subscription of push notification failed.");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Debug.Log("Push notification subscribed successfully.");
                    }
                });


                //installation.
            }
```

Comment: @thetnswe are you able to resolve the issue ?

Comment: No.. I haven't resolved it..

Answer (score 2):

"Parse Unity Push Sample not working", agree!! boy, such a pain in the (  Y  )

I've been fighting with Unity Parse Pushes for days(a week?) and I just solve it. I am so, so, happy, I want to share my happiness (first time in my life I write at StackOverflow, guess it was about time...)

Not sure if this will solve your problem, but for sure you have something wrong at this line:

```
 AndroidJavaObject currentActivity = unityPlayer.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
```

We have to change *"currentActivity"* for what ever is your current activity. In my case I have written this:

```
AndroidJavaObject currentActivity = unityPlayer.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject> ("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerNativeActivity");
```

Because that's the name of my activity in my AndroidManifest.xml

```
  <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerNativeActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:screenOrientation="landscape">
      <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.ForwardNativeEventsToDalvik" android:value="true" />
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Still, it might not solve your problem. So, just in case, I copy paste my code!

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:installLocation="preferExternal" package="com.XXXX.YYYY" android:versionName="1" android:versionCode="7">
  <supports-screens android:smallScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" android:anyDensity="true" />
  <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" />
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />  
  <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />  
  <permission android:protectionLevel="signature"  android:name="com.XXXX.YYYY.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="com.XXXX.YYYY.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />   
  <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.CHECK_LICENSE" /> 
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />



  <application android:icon="@drawable/app_icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="false">

    <service android:name="com.parse.ParsePushService" />


    <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />              
        <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
        <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
        <category android:name="com.XXXX.YYYY" />
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerNativeActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:screenOrientation="landscape">
      <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.ForwardNativeEventsToDalvik" android:value="true" />
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen" />

    <!-- replace @drawable/push_icon with your push icon identifier -->
    <meta-data android:name="com.parse.push.notification_icon" android:resource="@drawable/app_icon"/>  
  </application>
</manifest>
```

Please, replace *com.XXXX.YYYY* by -your- bundle identifier, in case of *thetnswe* would be by *com.JoyDash.Movies*

(funny thing: there is no GCM BroadcastReceiver as the Parse Push samples says, it was spitting errors like this [error setting up push notification using parse.com and android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26355187/error-setting-up-push-notification-using-parse-com-and-android-studio))

And then I have a C# Unity Script in one of my GameObjects (actually the same than the one I use to initialize Parse):

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using Parse;


public class ParsePushRegistration : MonoBehaviour {
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        #if UNITY_ANDROID
        ParsePush.ParsePushNotificationReceived += (sender, args) => {                  
            AndroidJavaClass parseUnityHelper = new AndroidJavaClass ("com.parse.ParseUnityHelper");
            AndroidJavaClass unityPlayer = new AndroidJavaClass ("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
            AndroidJavaObject currentActivity = unityPlayer.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject> ("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerNativeActivity");

            // Call default behavior.
            parseUnityHelper.CallStatic ("handleParsePushNotificationReceived", currentActivity, args.StringPayload);
        };              
        #endif
    }
}
```

Hope it helps! If not, let me know... and we will see :)

Comment: Right after posting that, I made another push, and it did not work! I could not believe it. I have waited to see what's going on to give feedback. The thing is it only works if the Unity App is **not** in the background as a recente app. If it is there, or in the foreground, the notification will not show up (actually, that last situation is kind of normal). Still trying to solve this.

Comment: UnityPlayerNativeActivity deprecated , use UnityPlayerActivity